# Laravel Carbon\Carbon::setLastErrors() argument #1 ($lastErrors) must be of type array, bool given,

Tags: php, laravel

the error is :

```
Carbon\Carbon::setLastErrors(): Argument #1 ($lastErrors) must be of type array, bool given, called in 
C:\Users\tejassurve\Documents\code\jobhunt_project\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Traits\Creator.php on line 98
```

below is the line where error comes

```
self::setLastErrors(parent::getLastErrors());
```

Comment: run composer update it will solve

Answer (score 7):

Just run this command:

`composer update`

Comment: before running check version of your php, when you work on many php projects with many php versions you might messed up with versions

Answer (score 4):

If you can not change your PHP version to 8.1, you can update this line

File Path

./vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Traits/Creator.php

Line No:

928

Old Line

```php
private static function setLastErrors(array $lastErrors)
```

New Line

```php
private static function setLastErrors($lastErrors)
```

it work
thank you

Comment: While this _might_ work, you should never edit vendor packages directly. The issue is likely caused by something else and has a proper solution like updating the package for example.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This worked for me. I have a CRM which does not yet support my current PHP 8.2.3. While waiting for the next release, I used this as temporal solution which worked great.

Comment: As @D1__1 mentioned, you should never edit vendor packages directly because packages can be reset very easily during build.

Comment: @D1__1 Nothing wrong with a hotfix ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug for php version change.

Make sure you are using the correct php version as the `composer.json` file says.

To know your version of php just run:

```
php -v
```

In Homestead for example, to change the 7.4 php version just run the command:

```
php74
```